# How to add ListView in flutter Speed Dial?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

How can I add ListView or scrolling behavior in flutter_speed_dial 1.2.5. I am dynamically adding SpeedDialChild. How this possible?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This package uses `Stack` and `Positioned` to render the children. So there is no scroll feature. Do feature request here *flutter_speed_dial* [*issues*](https://github.com/darioielardi/flutter_speed_dial/issues).

*Edit:* Its already raised by someone [here](https://github.com/darioielardi/flutter_speed_dial/issues/35)

Comment: Okay, Thank you! Anyway,  can you refer me any of the other package with same function with scrollable behavior?